# Google Structured Data: "In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either price or review or availability needs to be present"

Tags: microformats, google-rich-snippets

When I test [this page](http://www.boxinghome.pl/pl/p/Rekawice-bokserskie-GREEN-HILL-TIGER-10-oz.-Czerwone/283) with Google Structured Data Testing Tool, I get this message:

```
hproduct
availability:   in_stock
brand-name: GREEN HILL
category:   Bokserskie
description:    Bardzo trwałe rękawice bokserskie GREEN HILL TIGER (10 OZ) Producent rękawic: Green Hill - Dostawca profesjonalnego sprzętu na szereg międzynarodowych imprez bokserskich (np. Olimpiada-...
fn: Rękawice bokserskie GREEN HILL - TIGER 10 oz. Czerwone
photo:  http://www.boxinghome.pl/environment/cache/images/300_200_productGfx_a52dca0949dd886f787e4e34d683741a.jpg
price:  189
currency:   PLN
Błąd: In order to generate a preview with rich snippets, either price or review or availability needs to be present.
```

I dont know what I am missing. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

You must specify the offer details itemscope and nest the price and availability inside it.

```
<span itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
INSERT PRICE, AVAILIBILITY and REVIEW metadata HERE
</span>
```

Here's an example from Google:

```
<span itemprop="offerDetails" itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Offer">
    Regular price: $179.99
    <meta itemprop="currency" content="USD" />
    $<span itemprop="price">119.99</span>
    (Sale ends <time itemprop="priceValidUntil" datetime="2020-11-05">
      5 November!</time>)
    Available from: <span itemprop="seller">Executive Objects</span>
    Condition: <span itemprop="condition" content="used">Previously owned, 
      in excellent condition</span>
    <span itemprop="availability" content="in_stock">In stock! Order now!</span>
  </span>
```

[Example from Google on how the microdata syntax should look](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/146750)

[Webmasters stackexchange question about rich snippets](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56881/google-stating-price-is-missing-from-product-rich-snippet-but-it-is-present)